# How to reformat asciidoc without breaking tables

Tags: vim, asciidoc

I am working on an asciidoc document with long lines and several tables, and I'd like to reformat the paragraphs to fit into 80 columns.

If I use Vim's formatting command, it breaks all asciidoc tables, because they exceed 80 columns as well.

Is there a tool that can reformat asciidoc?

What would be the best way to achive this?

Comment: This may be a little bit hacky... But you can probably accomplish this easily by telling Vim not to format comments with `:set fo-=q` and telling it that the `|` character starts a comment with `:set com+=:|`

Comment: I assume you mean `gq` when you refer to Vim's formatting command. Can you show us a few lines of the table you want to reformat? A well-formatted Asciidoc table should be relatively easy to constrain to 80 columns. If the table formatting is poor, it might require several passes of adjustments to get it right.